# Keyboard shortcut (or automator app) to open currently open finder window?

Tags: applescript, command-line, automator, shortcut, shortcuts-app

I have a Stream Deck and I am hoping I can make a button I can press that will activate finder and move me to a currently open finder window - just as if I clicked on Finder on the Dock. (I can do this for every other app by just launching the app) I figured out how to "launch" finder by launching the Finder app tucked away in the System folder, but it doesn't quite do what I want (see below.)

I've gotten very close from these other articles:

[Is there a keyboard shortcut to bring up Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114933/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-bring-up-finder)

[How to automate right clicking Finder's dock icon and choosing action?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/322902/how-to-automate-right-clicking-finders-dock-icon-and-choosing-action)

But they all do the same thing as

> `open -a Finder`

in terminal——they make Finder active, but *if I have a finder window open on another monitor in full screen* it does not move to it, it only shows Finder in the menu bar.

I can't seem to find a way emulate the exact action of clicking the icon in the dock, which *does indeed* jump to the correct "spaces desktop" (full screen Finder window) on another monitor, whether via keyboard shortcut, shortcuts app, stream deck's app, automator, AppleScript, or terminal command - however I am by no means an expert in automator, Shortcuts, AppleScript, or terminal.

I tried "watch me do" in automator, and it'd work if I didn't hide my dock, but I do. :/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out a way to do what I want, but I am still interested if there is a "cleaner" way (because this way makes the dock pop up when I run it.)

Stream Deck lets me run keyboard shortcuts, so in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Yvx6JcjPY4) I found that control-f3 activates the dock, and it always starts on finder, so then I have the same button run another keyboard shortcut - plain old Return - to activate it, which gives me the desired action.

Comment: It would be better if you included your "hack" in your question and modify the question accordingly to ask for what you actually need at this time.